# Duda sobre HTML, cambiando plantilla de wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Tengo unas dudas que no soy capaz de solventar en [mi página](http://www.meganfc.net). En la parte de abajo donde los iconos sociales, hay cuadrados en vez de los iconos de facebook, instagram, etc..., en cambio [en esta otra página](https://vps333602.ovh.net) si que se ven todos.

He imaginado que es un problema de forwarding, pero buscando en la base de datos no he encontrado nada relacionado con el nombre del elemento `fa fa-facebook`, `fa fa-instagram`, etc... asi que he optado por entrar en el código e intentar cambiarlo, pero la verdad es que no tengo demasiada idea.

El código del `footer` en cuestión es este: http://pastebin.com/s72Rk5WM
y el trozo de còdigo correspondiente es:

```
 /* facebook */
 if( !empty($zerif_socials_facebook) ):
   echo '<li><a'.$attribut_new_tab.' href="'.esc_url($zerif_socials_facebook).'"><span class="sr-only">' . __( 'Go to Facebook', 'zerif-lite' ) . '</span> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>';
 endif;
```

He intentado insertar la imagen con `src`, pero no lo he conseguido y tampoco sé cómo guardarla, imagino que el `i class`, es lo que indica la imagen, pero no tengo manera de localizarlo.

Necesito ayuda para que aparezcan mis iconos en mi página como lo hacen en la otra de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los iconos vienen de la fuente fontawesome. En la pagina que funciona se esta cogiendo la fuente desde esta URL:

```
http://www.meganfc.net/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3
```

Es comun usar fontawesome font para los iconos. Aqui te dejo el enlace para usar el de facebook.

http://fontawesome.io/icon/facebook/

Comprueba que estas cargando la fuente desde tu pagina. No me deja acceder a ella por lo que no puedo comprobarlo yo.